# checkboxes in html form wont check when clicked even with labels : Here's the whole form

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox

Some of the checkboxes in my form are not checking when clicked

I've tried wrapping them with the label as this usually does the trick for people but this hasn't changed anything for me, even if I get rid of the text for each checkbox it still doesn't check. I'm not sure what else it could be.

```html
<div class = "register">
    <form action="register.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username ..."><p />
                    <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password ..."><p />
                    <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="someone@somesite.com"><p />
                    <input type="gender" name="gender" value="" placeholder="Male or Female ..."><p />
                    <input type="sport" name="sport" value="" placeholder="Favorite Sport..."><p />
                                    <input type="age" name="age" value="" placeholder="Age ..."><p />
      <h1 class="h4">Favorite Player</h2>
        <br><br>
        <label><input type='checkbox' name='response1' value='response1'>Ronaldo</label>
        <label><input type='checkbox' name='response2' value='response2'>Messi</label>
        <label><input type='checkbox' name='response3' value='response3'>Ibra</label>
        <label><input type='checkbox' name='response4' value='response4'>Me</label>
        <br><br>
        <h1 class="h4">Favorite Color</h2>
          <br><br>
          <label><input type='checkbox' name='noise1' value='noise1'>Red</label>
          <label><input type='checkbox' name='noise2' value='noise2'>Blue</label>
          <label><input type='checkbox' name='noise3' value='noise3'>ME!</label>
          <br><br>
          <h1 class="h4">Level of Cleanliness/Organization Preference </h1><br><br><br><br>
          <input type='checkbox' name='room1' value='room1' class='heads'><img src="https://cdn-image.travelandleisure.com/sites/default/files/styles/1600x1000/public/1446151328/miami-header-dg1015.jpg?itok=eIwFd7q_" width="250" height="250" /><br>
          <input type='checkbox' name='room2' value='room2' class='heads'><img src="https://images.musement.com/cover/0002/49/thumb_148242_cover_header.jpeg?w=1200&h=630&q=60&fit=crop" width="250" height="250" /> <br>
          <input type='checkbox' name='room3' value='room3' class='heads'><img src="place.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
          <h1 class="h4">Do you want a account?</h2>
            <br><br><br><br>
            <label><input type='checkbox' name='r1' value='r1'>Yes</label>
            <label><input type='checkbox' name='r2' value='r2'>No</label>
            <br><br>
            <h1 class="h4">Do you need a account?</h2>
              <br><br>
              <label><input type='checkbox' name='r3' value='r3'>Yes</label>
              <label><input type='checkbox' name='r4' value='r4'>No</label>
              <br><br>

              <br><br>
br><br>
            

<?php
                if(isset($_POST['r3']))
                {
                    echo '   <h1 class = "h4">How did you find us?</h2><br><br>             <input type="location" name="location" value="" placeholder="Zip Code or Full address"><p />';
                
                }
            ?>
            <br><br>
              
              <input type="submit" name="createaccount" value="Create Account">
    </form>
</div class = "register">
```

To have the checkboxes check when clicked

Comment: Four times you open a h1 tag and close it with a h2. Also, the code you posted doesn't have the issues you described. We need a [mcve]

Comment: wow thanks but that didn't help

Comment: what do you mean id doesn't have those issues it works for you?

Comment: Every checkbox works fine

Comment: I mean that your example works fine. The boxes are checked when clicking. Perhaps you're missing some CSS that's causing the issue?

Comment: @Bubba try pressing the 'Run Code' button in the question as edited above. The checkboxes should check. (They do for me.) Try to update the question with anything that makes it not work in the code it came from. Check out the link about Minimal, Complete, etc. above, for what will help you get helpful answers here.

Comment: Can someone put it on hold instead of closing? Give the OP a chance to edit.

Comment: @Bubba you should use radio buttons instead of checkboxes for your Yes/No options (as you should disallow checking both yes and no for these answers)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to check the boxes when running the code snippet included with your question.

As a possible solution for your environment, instead of:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='response2' value='response2'>Messi</label>
```

Try the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Messi" name="Messi"> <label for="Messi">Messi</label>
```